# Combine RegionDifference with Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I have this 2D graphics

```
a1 = {-1, Sqrt[3]};
a2 = {1, Sqrt[3]};
unitCell[x_, y_] := {Black, Disk[{x, y}, 0.1], Black, 
  Disk[({x, y} + a1/2), 0.1], Black, Disk[({x, y} + a2/2), 0.1], Blue,
   Thickness[0.001], Line[{{x, y}, {x, y} + a1/2}], 
  Line[{{x, y}, {x, y} + a2/2}], 
  Line[{{x, y} + a2/2, {x, y} + a2/2 - (a2 - a1)/2}], 
  Line[{{x, y} + a2/2, {x, y} + a2}], 
  Line[{{x, y} + a1/2, {x, y} + a1}], 
  Line[{{x, y} + a1/2, {x, y} + a1/2 - (a2 - a1)/2}]};
ff2=Graphics[{Table[
   unitCell @@ (a1 j + a2 k), {j, -5, 5}, {k, -5, 5}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}]
```

I would like to exclude points outside a disk of radius r (i.e. show only points inside the red or green circle as below.

[image]

This is how I did it be not working

```
r=2    
desirdReg= RegionDifference[ff2, Disk[{0, 0}, r]];
    Region[desirdReg]
```

it gives:

```
RegionDifference::reg:  is not a correctly specified region.
```

I would like to get something like this

[image]

Comment: What are the definitions of unitVectA and unitVectB?

Comment: @demm they are a1 and a2, code modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using patterns and deleting the unwanted `Disk` and `Line` objects.

```
reg = Disk[{3/4, 0}, 2];

ff2 = {Table[unitCell @@ (a1 j + a2 k), {j, -5, 5}, {k, -5, 5}]};

Graphics[DeleteCases[
  ff2, (Disk[{x_, y_}, r_] /; {x, y} \[NotElement] reg) | 
       (Line[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] /; ({x1, y1} \[NotElement] reg || 
       {x2, y2} \[NotElement] reg)), All]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
dsk = Disk[{0, Sqrt[3]}, Sqrt[3]];

reg = RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@dsk, DiscretizeGraphics[ff2]];

cropped = MeshPrimitives[reg, All];

Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], AbsolutePointSize[10], cropped}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{First@ff2, AbsoluteThickness[3], AbsolutePointSize[7], 
  MapThread[{##} &, {{ Blue, Red}, Reverse@cropped}], Opacity[.5], 
  Green, Circle @@ dsk}, PlotRange -> 4]
```

[image]